# count the times a year between multiple periods

Tags: r

My data looks more or less like this (with in the column car being car ID's, so each line represents one car, and the period during it was active):

```
structure(list(car = c(100987, 100995, 104641, 120350, 123444, 128248, 128253, 129537, 129612, 130189), 
  location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "A", "B", "D", "C", "C"), class = "factor"), 
  start = structure(c(12784, 12784, 365, 15027, 15951, -1096, 7305, 365, 365, -731), class = "Date"), 
  end = structure(c(16070, 16070, 16070, 16070, 16070, 13725, 16070, 16070, 16070, 16070), class = "Date")), 
 .Names = c("car", "location", "start", "end"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe as follows:

```
output=data.frame(location=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=2),year=rep(2000:2001,3),n_cars=10:15)
```

So I would like to count, per location, how many cars there are over a range of years (say 2000:2013). A car only counts if it was there on the 31st of december of that year. I thought about making for each entry a list of years during which that car was active and then make the count of list items that contain that year. But my dataframe is too big to make that an efficient approach. How would I do this best? It seems an easy thing to do but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is column `car` in your data set the count of cars?

Comment: no, it's an ID. I'll change it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
library(gdata)

# dat is the name of your original data set structure

yeardf <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
    if(yday(dat$end[i]) > 364)
       years_active <- paste(seq(year(dat$start)[i], year(dat$end)[i]))
    else
       years_active <- paste(seq(year(dat$start)[i], year(dat$end)[i]-1))
    car <- paste(rep(dat$car[i], length(years_active)))
    location <- as.character(rep(dat$location[i], length(years_active)))
    df <- data.frame(car = car, location = location, year = years_active)
    yeardf <- rbind(yeardf, df)
}

output <- ddply(yeardf, .(location, year), 'nrow')
output <- rename.vars(output, 'nrow', 'n_cars')
```

Comment: Thanks, this codes works, but I would like to have the year when "31/12/X" is included, so if the period ends at 15/01/2004, 2004 shouldn't be included. I checked ?year but there's no such option.

Comment: You just need to add an if statement within the loop.  If end date is greater than 364, include the year.  If it doesn't, exclude it.  You might have to come up with some logic if it's a leap year and the car is "retired" on 12/30, but that should be fairly straightforward.